# Google Sign In user agent issue in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, google-signin

I am using google sign in my app. I have configured via firebase with the steps given in the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin. My prob is, when i open my app in iPhone, it redirects to the mobile browser and works absolutely fine. But when i open app in iPad, it opens up in a webview and hence the user agent issue occurs.

[image]

Can someone suggest how can i force the app to go to browser even it is opened in iPad.

I have attached my code for reference

```
 @available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool
{
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: [:])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
{
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?)
{
    if error != nil {
        // ...
        print(error!)

        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                      accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

        print(user!)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

        self.view.hideToastActivity()
        self.getUserDetails(email: (user?.email)!)

        if error != nil {
            // ...
            print(error!)

            return
        }
    }
}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user:GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...

    if error != nil {
        // ...
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: are you implemented this method func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } that called when you click sign in button ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the GTM-OAuth2 library, google had mentioned that it had deprecated the use of web-views which the GTM-OAuth2 library depends on. They have suggested to use the [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) library instead.